What's the meaning of "tremendous significance" in this context

People pardoned our hazy lack of details through realisation of the
shock the sad event must have caused us, and believed us when we
explained that the mangling action of the wind had rendered all eleven
bodies unsuitable for transportation outside. Indeed, I flatter myself
that even in the midst of our distress, utter bewilderment, and
soul-clutching horror, we scarcely went beyond the truth in any
specific instance. The tremendous significance lies in what we dared
not tell—what I would not tell now but for the need of warning others
off from nameless terrors.

I don't get the phrase "tremendous significance" here. It feels like there's something missing in this sentence, making the meaning hard to get, but I can't quite put my finger on what exactly is wrong with it. Maybe it should have been "tremendous significance of "?
Could someone help me please?
Source: https://www.hplovecraft.com/writings/texts/fiction/mm.aspx

Although there might be some wordplay (from the etymology "to be trembled at") this can be read completely literally "tremendous"= great in importance  "significance"= the quality of being worthy of attention.   I'd agree that it means "The significance of these events"

I think Lovecraft is using 'tremendous' in the sense 'awe-inspiring' rather than the casual usage relating to the size of something. If there is something missing it could be "The tremendous significance [of the events described] lies in ..."

The 'tremendous significance', is that of what the narrator and his/her fellows  dared not tell (something awful and creepy, obviously, this being Lovercraft).

I might add a personal remark - HP Lovecraft was a truly bad writer, if anyone deserved that description. No good can come of reading the dreadful rubbish he produced.

Lovecraft wrote almost entirely for pulp magazines.

@WeatherVane - he was one of the most horribly racist writers I have ever encountered.

@MichaelHarvey His father and mother ended up in the loony bin. And the wife was nuts, too, it seems. He seems to be the "father of American horror" except for Edgar Allen Poe. The Wikipedia page on him is pretty good: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H._P._Lovecraft But what a whacko, huh?

So just to make sure I'm not misunderstanding anything, the sentence should be read like this:
I flatter myself that [...] when describing the tragedy, we scarcely went beyond the truth in any specific instance. But the key thing about our description of this tragedy isn't that it contain any falsehood. It's what we left out.
Is that correct? Is there any nuances that I missed with my paraphrase?
And @Harvey: yeah, Lovecraft's prose is truly an acquired taste lol. But I'm required to get through this book for a thing I'm doing, so dropping it halfway isn't an option for me.

@Lambie - there's a 2001 Spanish horror film Dagon, which is based on the Lovecraft story of the same name, that we found sort of stupidly amusing, in a so-bad-it's-good kind of way.

@user3801280 - yes, I think you have it right. Personally, I might re-evaluate a 'thing that I was doing' that required me to give head space to HP Lovecraft.

@Lambie - 'loony bin', 'nuts' - it seems the language you use about people who are struggling with their mental health exactly mirrors mine!

@Lambie - Some of Colin Wilson manages to be nastily weird, e.g. The Miind Parasites. He wrote it after expressing a liking for Lovecraft's ideas, but a dislike for his ponderous prose, at the urging of August Derleth, another writer in this genre who I don't like.

@MichaelHarvey I believe you. I was just wondering to what extent a completely neurotic (today, they say dysfunctional, not a great term as they actually function in craziness) family like this is likely to produce a writer like that. What a creepo. (Yes, I'm otherizing him, haha). I can take Poe, but not this guy.

Read it as "The most important thing is what we dared not tell."

The tremendous significance lies in what we dared not tell—what I would not tell now but for the need of warning others off from nameless terrors.
lies=is found in
Explanation:
The huge or very important significance is found in what we dared not tell (recount), and which I would not tell now were it not for [if there was not the need for warning others] the need to warn others away from nameless terrors.
warn others away: tell others to stay away from them.
Short form of the idea:
In other words, I am only telling  you about these nameless terrors [whatever those are] because I need to warn you about how important they are for you to know in order to avoid them.
